# Splitting folders into training and testing set

Tags: python

I have 5 folders for Enron email dataset. I want to split enron1, enron3, enron5 into Training set and enron2,enron4 as Testing set in python.
I can load full dataset and split. but can't put as mentioned earlier.

```
for i in range(1,6):
    # folder containing the 2 categories of documents in individual folders.
    movie_data = load_files(f"/Users/mehedihasan/Desktop/Study/SEM6/COMP723 Data Mining & Knowledge Engineering/Assignment/email data/enron{i}") 
    X = np.append(X, movie_data.data)
    y = np.append(y, movie_data.target)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

Comment: maybe run separatelly `for i in [1,3,5]:` and separatelly `for i in [2, 4]:`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `for i in [1,3,5]:` and `for i in [2, 4]:` instead of `range(1, 6)`

```
for i in [1,3,5]:
    # ... code ..
    X_train = ...
    y_train = ...

for i in [2, 4]:
    # ... code ..
    X_test = ...
    y_test = ...
```

---

**BTW:**

If you have more folders then you can use

- `range(1, n, 2)` to get `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...`
- `range(2, n, 2)` to get `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...`